# FitNesse: workflow of creating tests using RestFixture

Tags: fitnesse, restfixture

Newbie to FitNesse, I want to test Rest APIs using RestFixture but did not know where to start.

Can someone give me step by step workflow and the sample decision table for GET, POST, and DELETE requests?

We use JSON responses, how can I input them in the decision tables when posting it?

Thanks

Comment: Not a real answer to your question, but you could also consider using Json Http Test (https://github.com/fhoeben/hsac-fitnesse-fixtures/wiki/2.-Slim-Fixtures#httptest) to test your REST API. Sample usage is documented in http://fhoeben.github.io/hsac-fitnesse-fixtures/examples-results/HsacExamples.SlimTests.HttpTests.JsonHttpTest.html

Answer (score 19):

This answer provides a cookbook to install RestFixture and a section to present the Acceptance test framework.

## Installation

One way to understand how to start with RestFixture is look at [RestFixtureLiveDoc](https://github.com/smartrics/RestFixtureLiveDoc). The project provides the documentation for RestFixture itself and it is managed by Maven. Should you prefer going this way, please read below.

### Assumptions

- you have a valid and working JDK installed (try from command prompt `java -version`)
- you have maven installed (try `mvn --version`)
- you have a version control software installed. Although, I won't discuss how to use it in the context of this answer.

### Cookbook

1. Create an empty Maven project (as explained [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html)). In a nutshell:

   `mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=smartrics.restfixture.sample -DartifactId=scratch -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false`

   - *Change the names of the group and artifact accordingly, to suite you*
   - Remove the files `src/test/java/smartrics/restfixture/sample/*.java` `src/main/java/smartrics/restfixture/sample/*.java`
2. `cd scratch` (*or to whatever name you have chosen*) and edit `pom.xml`
3. Add the RestFixture dependency (the latest version of RestFixture is [here](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.fitnesse%22%20AND%20a%3A%22fitnesse%22)). For example:

```xml
<dependency>
        <groupId>smartrics.restfixture</groupId>
        <artifactId>smartrics-RestFixture</artifactId>
        <version>4.1</version>
</dependency>
```

4. Add the Maven dependencies plugin to copy dependencies locally (*this is not necessary but I find it convenient*)

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/dependencies</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

5. Right now, you should be able to `mvn package` and build/copy dependencies (check them in the `target/dependencies` directory)
6. You may want to update to the latest FitNesse version (*Check the latest version available [here](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.fitnesse%22%20AND%20a%3A%22fitnesse%22)*), by adding

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.fitnesse</groupId>
    <artifactId>fitnesse</artifactId>
    <version>20151230</version>
</dependency>
```

7. Then do `mvn clean package`
8. Create a file `start.bat` with this content, to create a start command for fitnesse (*On Linux you should be able to create an equivalent `start.sh`*):

```sh
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set CLASSPATH="
for /R target\dependencies %%a in (*.jar) do (
  set CLASSPATH=!CLASSPATH!;%%a
)
set CLASSPATH=!CLASSPATH!"
java -cp !CLASSPATH! fitnesseMain.FitNesseMain -p 9090 -d src\main\resources -e 0
```

9. start FitNesse with the `start.bat` (*it will take some time for FitNesse to create all the relevant resources*)

   - From your browser go to `http://localhost:9090` to check it works
   - You can stop FitNesse with `CTRL-C`
10. You should at this point consider to commit to version control. If you use git, these items may be added to the ignore list:

```xml
target/
src/main/resources/FitNesseRoot/files/testResults
src/main/resources/FitNesseRoot/ErrorLogs
src/main/resources/FitNesseRoot/RecentChanges
src/main/resources/FitNesseRoot/properties
src/main/resources/FitNesseRoot/updateDoNotCopyOverList
src/main/resources/FitNesseRoot/updateList
src/main/resources/FitNesseRoot/Fitnesse/UserGuide
src/main/resources/FitNesseRoot/PageFooter
src/main/resources/FitNesseRoot/PageHeader
src/main/resources/FitNesseRoot/TemplateLibrary
```

11. With FitNesse running, got to the home page and edit.

    - Add this wiki word `MyTestSamples` somewhere in the page, then save.
    - You should see `MyTestSamples[?]` because the page doesn't exist.
    - Click on the question mark to edit the page
    - Append the following lines

    `!define TEST_SYSTEM {slim}
    !path target/dependencies/*.jar`

    to add a reference to the RestFixture classes and dependencies and use the [Slim Test system](http://www.fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.WritingAcceptanceTests.SliM)

    - Save the page.
12. In the `MyTestSamples` page Add a new Test page from the Add menu.

    - call the page `MySample1`, save
13. Go to `MySample1`, edit the page and type the following content. Then save

```
| Import |
| smartrics.rest.fitnesse.fixture |

|Table: Rest Fixture | http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/ |
| GET |/users | 200 | Content-Type : application/json; charset=utf-8 | jsonbody.length == 10|
```

14. If all went OK, by hitting Test on the page, the test should run and pass.

*You could achieve the same setup by constructing the project by hand by downloading and unzipping the RestFixture with dependencies (download from the link bin.zip [here](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22smartrics-RestFixture%22)). But I find the Maven approach simpler in the longer run.*

### Logging

RestFixture uses slf4j but doesn't come with logger bridge. To complete the configuration of the logging system add the following dependencies:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.20</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.20</version>
</dependency>
```

Then create the configuration file at `src\main\resources\log4j.xml` with the following content

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/" debug="false">
    <appender name="FILE" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
        <param name="file" value="restfixture.log" />
        <param name="append" value="false" />
        <param name="threshold" value="debug" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601} %-5p [%c{1}] - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <category name="smartrics.rest.client" additivity="false">
        <priority value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </category>
    <category name="smartrics.rest.fitnesse.fixture" additivity="false">
        <priority value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </category>
    <category name="httpclient.wire" additivity="false">
        <priority value="ERROR" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </category>
    <root>
        <priority value="ERROR" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

The `httpclient.wire` logger can be set to DEBUG to observe HTTP traffic on the wire.

For logging in the FitNesse server (outside the scope of this tutorial) [check here](http://www.fitnesse.org/FitNesse.FullReferenceGuide.UserGuide.AdministeringFitNesse.LogFiles)

**JUnit runner**:

FitNesse tests can be run via [JUnit as well](http://www.fitnesse.org/FitNesse.FullReferenceGuide.UserGuide.WritingAcceptanceTests.RunningFromJunit), using the [Maven Surefire plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/).

Create a test class runner in `src/test/java/smartrics/restfixture/sample/RunnerTest.java`

```java
package smartrics.restfixture.sample;

import java.io.File;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import fitnesse.junit.JUnitHelper;

public class RunnerTest {

    private JUnitHelper helper;

    @Before
    public void prepare() {
        helper = new JUnitHelper("src/main/resources", new File("target", "fitnesse-junit").getAbsolutePath());
        helper.setPort(9090);
    }

    @Test
    public void restFixtureTests() throws Exception {
        helper.assertSuitePasses("MyTestSamples.MySample1");
    }
}
```

Then install the surefire plugin in the pom file:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.17</version>
    <configuration>
        <forkMode>always</forkMode>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Save the pom.xml file and run `mvn clean package` to run the build with tests.
The build will pass and the report will be available in `/target/fitnesse-junit/MyTestSamples.MySample1.html`

**References**

- The pom.xml is [here](https://gist.github.com/smartrics/3db172f081604094421974d89d477740)
- The start.bat is [here](https://gist.github.com/smartrics/79589ec6fc7c6dfbe6308ae08b03f303)

## Acceptance tests

RestFixture has been designed to focus on the REST API exposed by the service under test. Mixing and matching Wiki content with structured fixtures does provide the best of both worlds for providing live documentation.

RestFixture can also be extended to provide additional functionality.

When writing acceptance tests focused on the API it's important highlight the parts of an HTTP request/response interaction: the VERB, the URI, the request/response BODY, the request/response HEADERs and the RETURN status code.

RestFixture does so by expressing each of these parts in a FitNesse table form:

```
| Table: Rest Fixture | <base uri> |
| setBody | <body> |
| setHeaders | <headers>
| VERB | /URI | <expected return status code> | <expected response headers | <expected response body> |
```

The `<expected ...>` cells may be empty. If empty, no expectation will be checked.

`setHeaders` and `setBody` are only relevant for verbs requiring an entity (POST, PUT, ...)

Moreover, by using `let` it's possible to extract data from parts of the HTTP response and share it with other fixtures and tests.

(RestFixtureLiveDoc)[1](https://github.com/smartrics/RestFixtureLiveDoc) has a comprehensive set of examples for the various features implemented by RestFixture, but here follows - for reference - an extract of the main ones.

**RestFixtureConfig**

(RestFixtureConfig)[11](https://github.com/smartrics/RestFixtureLiveDoc/blob/master/src/main/resources/FitNesseRoot/RestFixtureTests/RestFixtureConfig/content.txt) is a simple fixture to set RestFixture configuration parameters. Config parameters can be overridden in *named* config fixtures and passed on to RestFixture instances. For example

```
|Table: Rest Fixture Config | my_config |
| name1 | value1 | 
| name2 | value2 |

|Table: Rest Fixture | http://host:8080/path | my_config |
| ... |
```

**RestFixture operations**

The supported HTTP operations are: `GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, `DELETE`, `HEAD`, `OPTION`, `TRACE`. For example:

```
| Table: Rest Fixture |http://host:8080 |
|GET    | /resources/0 | 200 | Content-Type: application/json | jsonbody.name === 'Ted' |
```

OR

```
| Table: Rest Fixture |http://host:8080/path |
|GET    | /resources/0 | 200 | Content-Type: application/xml | //name[text()='Ted'] |
```

Depending on the information that the author may want to convey expectation cells (3rd, 4th and 5th cell on each row) may be supplied for verification.

Simple fixtures like the examples above may be provided to test and document the service exposed REST api.

**Sharing data**

Data is shared using `let` to extract from the response.

```
| Table: Rest Fixture |http://host:8080/path |
|GET    | /resources/0 | 200 | Content-Type: application/json | jsonbody.name === 'Ted' |
| let   |  name | js | response.jsonbody.name |  |
```

In here, the symbol `name` is set to the value of the json expression `response.jsonbody.name`. `response` is a json object containing the last HTTP response, `jsonbody` is an object in response containing the JSON object in the response body.

The symbol can be further used in other fixtures:

```
| setBody | { 'some_name' : '%name%' } |
```

or

```
| script | another fixture | 
| check | not null | $name |
```

**Transactions**

The system can be also test and documented for multiple operations providing an application transaction (in a lose meaning here).

```
| Table: Rest Fixture  |  http://host:port | 
| comment | an order is created ... |
| POST | /orders        | | |  |
| let  | orderIdUri     | header | Location: (.+) | |
| GET  | %orderIdUri    | | |  |
| let  | email          | js | response.jsonbody.address.email    |
| setBody |!- { 
    'payload' : {
       'message' : 'order sent',
       'email' : '%email%
     }
-!|
| comment | and a confirmation can be sent |
| POST | /notifications | 201 | |  |
```

The example above documents a way to use the API as an application transaction.

**Extending RestFixture**

RestFixture can be extended to provide additional functionality. Two methods are provided:

1. Via Java: extend the RestFixture java to add/change the behaviour. For examples check the (RestFixtureExtensions)[12](https://github.com/smartrics/RestFixtureExtensions) project.
2. Via Javascript: As described below

Simple Javascript  code can be embedded in RestFixture via configuration.

```
| Table: Rest Fixture Config |  imp |
| restfixture.javascript.imports.map | !- sampleJs=src/main/resources/FitNesseRoot/files/javascript/sample.js -|
```

The config above - when used - will load the Javascript in the file provided as path and make it available in the context of the expectations handler:

```
| Table: Rest Fixture |http://host:port | imp |
| GET   | /resources/1.json | 200 |  |  |      
| let   | sum | js | var sum = sampleAdd(1, 2); sum;| |
```

Comment: Need help..When i use this i m getting an error ReferenceError: "sampleAdd" is not defined. (unnamed script#1)  . My fixture cfg is | Table: Rest Fixture Config |  imp |
| restfixture.javascript.imports.map | !-sampleJs=js/sample.js-! |

Comment: @Cshah you need to make sure the js file path in the imports map is correct

Comment: Agreed.I m not able to debug.How can i troubleshoot if the location is wrong..anyway i can print the content of js or absolute path of js

Comment: If you have correctly configured the logging system you should see the path in the log output

Comment: Also, the feature you are trying to use is implemented in RestFixture 4.1 and above

Comment: @smartrics: `http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com` is now returning an error on GET: `Access denied | jsonplaceholder.typicode.com used CloudFlare to restrict access`.  Googling this it appears JSONPlaceholder is checking the user agent and blocking any from automated systems that could possibly be used in a DDoS attack.  Workaround: Add a setHeader row above the GET to spoof the user agent of a browser, which JSONPlaceholder  will let through..  EG `| setHeader | User-Agent : Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686) Gecko/20071127 Firefox/2.0.0.11 |`

Comment: Maybe you should be more specific in your plugins description. Where is that added in the pom.xml? Of course one can google that, but it's distracting to see a snippet with "add this in pom.xml" but no clue where to add it...

Comment: @Zordid - I am assuming a basic knowledge of maven... I don't want to diverge from the main point of the response which is the installation/configuration of RestFixture