# FitNesse: JSON schema validation using RestFixture

Tags: jsonschema, fitnesse, json-schema-validator, fitnesse-slim, restfixture

How can I perform JSON schema validation for my JSON response using libraries like `dojox.json.schema` or JSV or JSON Schema by writing Javascript code that sources these JS libraries.

I want to use let feature to assign a variable called `is_valid` which will run a JS code that validates the response against a JSON schema.

The JS code might look like [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-jsonschema/).

Comment: ans at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35753103/workflow-of-creating-tests-using-restfixture

Answer (score 0):

I was using the wrong version of restFixture. Once i migrated to ver 4.2 from 3.x, it started working fine.