# Fitnesse JSON expectation syntax

Tags: json, fitnesse, restfixture

In reference to [workflow of creating tests using RestFixture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35753103/workflow-of-creating-tests-using-restfixture/36298133#36298133), I am asking myself, what kind of syntax the following statement represents:

```
jsonbody.name === 'Ted'
```

I need to know all possibilities of this kind of syntax to write down the expected value for much more complex JSON responses.
Is there a name or reference for the type of syntax that is used here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is Javascript syntax. `jsonbody` is a variable containing the response.

See [JavascriptExpectations in RestFixtureLiveDoc](https://github.com/smartrics/RestFixtureLiveDoc/blob/master/src/main/resources/FitNesseRoot/RestFixtureTests/JavascriptExpectations/content.txt) for more details. E.g.:

> As of RestFixture Version 2, a javascript engine is embedded to allow expectations in Javascript on response body contents in JSON format.
>
> !**** XPaths and JSON
>   For backward compatibility XPath expressions are maintained and executed
>   ****!
>
> After a successful response is received with content type "application/json" the expectation cell in a .RestFixture row is
>   interpreted as a string with Javascript and executed within the context of the response body.

An example:

> ```
> | Table: Rest Fixture |http://${jettyHost}:${jettyPort}|
> |GET    | /resources/%id%.json | 200 |Content-Type : application/json |!-
> jsonbody.resource.name=="test post" && jsonbody.resource.data=="some data"
> -!|
> ```